# What would you call a picture where all the main characters are together?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, image-identification

What is a picture showing the main cast, called in English?
For example, in [this picture](http://television2day.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/friends-season.jpg):

[image: tableau from Friends]

What would you call this kind of picture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can consider **ensemble poster** as well. These pictures are usually posters and usually includes the **ensemble photography** of the cast.

> An [ensemble cast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_cast) is made up of cast members in which the principal actors and performers are assigned roughly equal amounts of importance and screen time in a dramatic production.

From [Friends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friends):

> Series creator David Crane wanted all six actors to be equally prominent, and the series was lauded as being "the first true 'ensemble' show".

There are different styles of ensemble posters also. You can check this link:
http://www.empireonline.com/features/ensemble-movie-poster-styles/11.asp

Comment: the link convinced me that this is what i was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It’s just a *cast shot*.

If you want something fancier, you might be able to wedge in something like *tableau*, but that’s a bit pretentious.

Answer (score 0):

A **publicity still**: [also known as **film stills** or **production stills**) are official photographs taken on or off the set of a movie or television program during production. The photos are taken by studio photographers for promotional purposes.](http://fanlore.org/wiki/Publicity_Still)